# Command to minimize or maximize from within a batch File

Tags: windows, command-line, batch-file

I run a scheduled batch file minimized. START /MIN did not work well for this purpose -- it would momentarily flash maximized -- so I switched to using NIRCMD EXEC HIDE. That works well.

Now there's a new need. If the batch file runs into a problem (e.g., it finds that a certain desired program is not currently running), I want it to stop and notify me. This would be no problem if the batch file were already running in the ordinary DOS fashion, minimized or not. But it seems NIRCMD EXEC HIDE really deep-sixes the running process.

Is there a way to hide a batch file effectively, and yet to bring it back to visible normal or maximum size under certain conditions? I think I may be looking for an alternative to /MIN and NIRCMD that involves toggling commands within the batch file.

Comment: Maybe PowerShell would be of use? It has better ways of prompting the user

Comment: You can change the amount of rows and columns, using MODE ROWS= COLS= (or something like that. It will make the window larger/smaller. Maybe that will help? Also, a great way to attract attention is by using color xy to change the color, where x and y are a hex value of 0-F.

Comment: not sure if this will help you - https://github.com/npocmaka/batch.scripts/blob/master/hybrids/.net/c/windowMode.bat

Comment: You could try creating a shortcut to your batch file and set it to start minimized, then schedule this shortcut instead of the batch file directly. I tried it and it works for me - but then again, using `START /MIN` also works for me without flashing anything, so I can't tell if it's any better. Another option is using a message box for the alert instead of a printout, if that's a viable option - that would probably still show even with the batch window hidden.

Comment: Ray - It sounds like you need to add the logic in the batch script to log to a file or a temp file, etc. & then if the logic within the script confirms some process is not running, then you can use msg to do something like "`msg %username% "Cannot verify MyProcess is running per the %~FPNX0 job. Please check it's log file for more detail."`" & that'll be your indicator. Otherwise you could have it send you an email & attach the log, etc. with PowerShell or command line email client such as `sendmail` perhaps. It's possible but I wouldn't worry about trying to see the console to troubleshoot.